# SoundCloud Api - How to make (set) playlists favorites?

Tags: javascript, php, soundcloud

Is there any way to set playlist favorites in SoundCloud

For Track Favorites i am using

```
 SC.put('/me/favorites/'+track_id);
```

but its not working in playlist. It seems that "/favorites" only shows tracks and no playlists? Maybe there is another way to check if a playlist was marked as "like", but I did not find anything useful.

When Playlist getting error

```
{"errors":[{"error_message":"404 - Not Found"}]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work. Added callback for debugging.

```
SC.put('/e1/me/playlist_likes/' + playlist_id, function(data, err) {
    if(err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
    console.log(data);
});
```